# Apache Storm local cluster "Unable to canonicalize address"

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm trying to run a local cluster with this command:

```
storm local target/myjar.jar com.app.MyMainClass
```

Storm responds with this error:

```
WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server localhost/<unresolved>:2000, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address localhost/<unresolved>:2000 because it's not resolvable
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:65) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1001) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1060) [storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

The topology will submit fine when using a dockerized setup with zookeeper, nimbus, and supervisor containers. I'm using a homebrew installation of storm when running locally, but so far I can't find any similar issues online.

Comment: We are currently having the same problem. It seems related to Java 14 and https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8232369 Have you found a solution?

Comment: Some more digging done. Seems to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3779. This version of zk is still used internally by storm in the shaded deps. So, an intermittent, ugly solution could be to switch to another (lower) Java version. I will try to find a better solution.

Comment: I have also faced same issue with storm 2.2.0, when I downgraded it to 2.1.0 it started working in local mode. Cluster mode had no problems in 2.2.0 and 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to debug in a new environment using STS 4.8.0. Using STS 3.9.10 was the solution for me.