# StormCrawler: Unable to canonicalize address

Tags: stormcrawler

When running StormCrawler using the ElasticSearch archetype version 2.1.0, in combination with Apache Storm version 2.2.0 and OpenJDK 11, I get the following error when running the default topology:

```
10:51:54.160 [main-SendThread(localhost:2000)] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server localhost/<unresolved>:2000, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address localhost/<unresolved>:2000 because it's not resolvable
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:65) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1001) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1060) [storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
```

What does this mean and how can it be corrected?

Comment: Hi! How did you install Storm? (Ansible? Docker? Manual?) 
Any other exceptions in the nimbus or supervisor logs? Can you see the Storm UI at all?
BTW to use it with Java 11, you need to change the Storm config - see https://www.mail-archive.com/user@storm.apache.org/msg09830.html

Answer (score 0):

Just found this sorry for the late reply but just in case someone else has this problem

According to [Apache Storm local cluster "Unable to canonicalize address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804162/apache-storm-local-cluster-unable-to-canonicalize-address), this can be fixed by using Storm 2.1.0